# How can I combine session management for both the "SignInWithGoogle" firebase method and the "CustomLogin" function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have two login options available. The first option uses Firebase's select prompt, which sets up the session manager based on Firebase's SignInWithGoogle. It retrieves the user object from the Google Gmail ID and then checks the username and password in my database. In case the user does not exist, it prompts the user for registration.

Now i have to manage the session for when user manually enters username and password to login.

for signInWithGoogle i am using firebase auth and firebase inbuilt functions for setting up session.

confused in now how to implement the custom session login as it uses different user object than the signInwithGoogle.

Now, the dilemma I am facing is that I am currently using session management with the SignInWithGoogle method. However, I also want to set up session management with the custom login function, when the user manually enters the username and password.

I would like to know how I can combine both methods of session management to be used in the header file.

I am malso confused in as i want to use the best possible safest way to handle session for custom login out of cookie and localstorage option.

Is it possible to use the firebase inbuilt session management library methods for my custom login option where i am  response is returned form mysql db instead of object used by google prompt which checks and responce with the account of email and create account based on google gmail object user info.

auth.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getAuth, getIdToken } from "firebase/auth";
import { getIdTokenResult } from "firebase/auth";

import axios from "axios";
import {
  signOut,
  signInWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  setPersistence,
  browserSessionPersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL;

setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    // Session persistence successfully set
    console.log("Session persistence set");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Failed to set session persistence
    console.error("Failed to set session persistence", error);
  });

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });

export const signInWithGoogle = async (event, handleShowPasswordForm) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  try {
    await setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence); // Set session persistence

    const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
    const { user } = result; //select
    // Check if the user is already registered in your backend
    const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/checkUser`, {
      email: user.email,
    });
    console.log("complete Response:", response);  //checked from mysql db and mysql table object
    console.log("complete user object google:", user);

    if (response.data.exists) {
      console.log("User already registered");
      // Perform login with the existing user
      const { id, role, firstName, username } = response.data;
      //  currentUser = { id, role, firstName ,username};
      //   const token = response.headers.authorization;
      //   console.log("Token:", token);
      handleAuthentication(user);
      if (response.data.role === "admin") {
        window.location.href = `${baseUrl}/`; // Redirect to admin page for admin users
      } else {
        console.log("normal user");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("User not registered");
      // Extract the user's name from the email
      const [fname, lname] = user.displayName.split(" ");
      // Perform signup with the user's details
      // const password = prompt("Please enter a password:");
      // console.log(fname,lname ,user.email,user.password)
      handleShowPasswordForm(fname, lname, user.email);
      // handleSignup(fname, lname, user.email, password);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Sign in with Google failed", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const signOutUser = async () => {
  try {
    await signOut(auth);
    console.log("User signed out");
    handleAuthentication(null); // Pass null to indicate user signed out
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Sign out failed", error);
  }
};
// onAuthStateChanged(auth, handleAuthentication);
const handleAuthentication = async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in
    // console.log('User signed in:', user);
    const token = await getIdToken(user);
    const tokenResult = await getIdTokenResult(user);
    const { claims } = tokenResult;
    console.log("Claims:", claims);
    console.log("Token:", token);
    const displayName = user.displayName;
    console.log("DisplayName:", displayName);

    // Perform actions for logged in user, e.g., show user-specific content
    // Set state or update UI to reflect logged in state
    // Example: setLoggedIn(true);
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    console.log("User signed out");

    // Perform actions for logged out user, e.g., show login form
    // Set state or update UI to reflect logged out state
    // Example: setLoggedIn(false);
  }
};

const SessionManager = ({ updateUser }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen for authentication state changes
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      Promise.resolve().then(() => handleAuthentication(user));
      updateUser(user); // Update the user state
    });

    // Clean up the listener when the component unmounts
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default SessionManager;
export { handleAuthentication };
```

api.tsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { setPersistence,browserSessionPersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";

const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL;

export const handleLogin = async (username, password) => {
  try {

    const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/login`, {
      username,
      password,
    });





  
// handleAuthentication(response)
    // const { user, role } = response.data; // Extract the user and role from the response data
    //  const user = response.data;
    //  const token = response.headers.authorization;
    //   console.log("Token:", token);
    const token = response.headers.authorization;
    console.log("Token:", token);
    console.log(response.data);
    const { id, role,firstName, mail } = response.data;
 const user = { id, role, firstName, username };
console.log("fname :",response.data.firstName)
console.log("email :",firstName)
await setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence);
    handlecustomLoginAuthentication(user);
  //   const user = { id, role, firstName };

// currentUser = { id, role, firstName, username }; // Update the currentUser state
    // setCurrentUser(user);


  // await setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence);
  //   await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, username, password);

    // Perform actions based on the user role
    console.log("id:", response.data.id);
    if (response.data.role === "admin") {
      window.location.href = `${baseUrl}/`; // Redirect to admin page for admin users
    } else {
      console.log("normal user");
    }

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Login failed", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const handleSignup = async (fname, lname, email, password) => {
  try {
    // await setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence);

    const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/signup`, {
      fname,
      lname,
      email,
      password,
    });
    console.log("Login successful", response);
if(response){

}
    window.location.href = `${baseUrl}/`;
    console.error("Registered ");
    return response.data; // Return the response data if needed
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Signup failed", error.response);
    throw error; // Throw the error to be handled by the caller
  }
};

// You can define other functions for different API requests, such as POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.


const handlecustomLoginAuthentication = async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in
   
  // const { id, role, firstName, username } = user;
    console.log("User signed in now handle custom authentication:", user.role);
    // Perform actions for logged in user, e.g., show user-specific content
    // Set state or update UI to reflect logged in state
    // Example: setLoggedIn(true);
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    console.log("User signed out");

    // Perform actions for logged out user, e.g., show login form
    // Set state or update UI to reflect logged out state
    // Example: setLoggedIn(false);
  }
};
export const customSignOutUser = async () => {
  try {
    
    console.log("User signed out");
    handlecustomLoginAuthentication(null); // Pass null to indicate user signed out
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Sign out failed", error);
  }
};
```

header file

```
function MainHeader() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false);
const [showSignup, setShowSignup] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await signOut(auth);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Logout failed", error);
    }
  };

// component
  const handleShowLogin = () => {
    setShowLogin(true);
  };

  const handleCloseLogin = () => {
    setShowLogin(false);
  };

  const handleShowSignup = () => {
    setShowSignup(true);
  };

  const handleCloseSignup = () => {
    setShowSignup(false);
  };
//  const handleLogout = () => {
//     try {
//       handleLogout();
//     } catch (error) {
//       console.error("Logout failed", error);
//     }
//   };

//responisice menu for mobile 
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
<Fragment>

        
        <SessionManager updateUser={setUser} />  {/* Listen for authentication state changes */}
       
    <header className="border-b md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between p-4 pb-0 shadow-lg md:pb-4">
      {/* Logo text or image */}
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-4 md:mb-0">
        <h1 className="leading-none text-2xl text-grey-darkest">
       {user ? (<>   <p  className="no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-black">Welcome, {user.displayName}!</p></>) : (<>
          <Link
            href="/"
            className="no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-black"
          >
            Preview
          </Link></>) }
```